# LINQ object aggregation

Tags: c#, performance, linq, aggregation

I often see this kind of piece of code as an example of aggregating object enumerables in c#:

```
IEnumerable<MyCoolObject> myObjects = new List<MyCoolObject>()
{new MyCoolObject(){Value1=1, Value2=10}, new MyCoolObject(){Value1=2, Value2=20}};
MyCoolObject aggregatedObject = myObjects.Aggregate(new MyCoolObject(), (accumlator, next) => new MyCoolObject()
{ 
    Value1=accumlator.Value1 + next.Value1, 
    Value2=accumlator.Value2 + next.Value2
}
```

My problem with this approach is it creates a new MyCoolObject every iteration, wich seems like a huge waste.

The other common example is this:

```
MyCoolObject aggregatedObject = new MyCoolObject()
{
    Value1=myObjects.Sum(x=>x.Value1),
    Value2=myObjects.Sum(x=>x.Value2)
}
```

This one iterates my collection twice, also a big waste, espetially, if there are more fields to aggregate on my objects.

What I figured is, I could do this:

```
MyCoolObject aggregatedObject = myObjects.Aggregate(new MyCoolObject(), (accumlator, next) =>
{ 
    accumlator.Value1 += next.Value1;
    accumlator.Value2 += next.Value2;
    return accumlator;
};
```

This one creates a single accumlator object, works on it, and returns it, when finished. To me this looks to be on par with a manual foreach loop performance-wise.
I'm surprised, that I don't see this solution often. Are there any problems this solution can introduce, that could explain this?

Comment: 1) The examples you posted are *not* common. 2) Your code *also creates* one temporary object for each input row. Is it a typo? 3) The common usage is to add the current value to the accumulator and return the accumulator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I suspect that the object creation in his suggested code is just a typo. Other than that, I agree with you. :)

Comment: Indeed, the new object creation was a typo. Never copypaste your bad example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common usage is to modify the accumulator and then return it, not to create a new object. In this case, I'd expect to see the following code:

```
var aggregatedObject = myObjects.Aggregate(new MyCoolObject(),
    (accumulator, next) => {
       accumulator.Value1 +=next.Value1;
       accumulator.Value2 +=next.Value2;
       return accumulator;
    });
```

Returning a new object from the accumulating function makes sense only if modifying the accumulator has side effects. A good accumulator object though should *not* produce side effects. In such a case it would be better to use a different object type as the accumulator.